# How can i keep both cameras to move with the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two cameras. One is the Main Camera and the second is Camera is added.
I put both cameras under as child the ThirdPersonController.

The problem now is i can't move the player, when i use the WSAD keys it's rotating the player but not moving it anywhere.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    int count = 0;
    public Camera _mainCamera;
    public Camera _camera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _mainCamera.enabled = true;
        _camera.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            _mainCamera.enabled = !_mainCamera.enabled;
            _camera.enabled = !_camera.enabled;

            if (count == 0)
            {
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a empty gameobject and the escape key click switch is working. But when it's on the Camera view i can't move the player. When it's in the Main Camera i want that i won't be able even to rotate the player.

[image: Editor screenshot]

When it's in the Camera view i want to have full controll on the player when it's on the Main Camera view i want that i will not have any control on the player he will not move at all.

The problem now is that in both views when i click the escape key i can rotate the player and not moving him to any direction.

I want both cameras to follow the player but only the Camera to be with full control on the player when i switch to the Main Camera there should be no control at all on the player. I mean both will follow the player each camera in it's own position and view. so i can click the escape key and switch the view in any place in the game.

Main Camera view:

[image: Main camera view]

And Camera view

[image: Camera view]

So both camera will follow the player in this positions so when ever in the game i will click the escape key and switch between views i will see it like in the screenshots.

Comment: Not exactly related to your problem, but your `count` should be a `bool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use SetActive(boolean) instead of enabling and disabeling. Enable just truns on and off the Camera Component, the script with the rotation still works. If this doesn't solve your problem, please send us your code for both cameras.